# Tcl version change issue from 8.4 to 8.5.12

Tags: tcl, tclsh

I have a problem with changing tcl version from 8.4 to 8.5.12 on RHEL machine. Our product uses TclDevKit components like Tcldom, Tclxml, etc. Also we are using Incr Tcl (Itcl). I am trying to create pkgIndex.tcl file in Itcl in order to find Itcl when that package is required as follown:

```
package ifneeded Itcl 3.4 [list load [file join $dir "libitcl-O.a"] Itcl ]
```

but when I use

```
package require Itcl
```

Getting report: **couldn't load file "/somepath/itcl/lib/libitcl-O.a": /somepath/lib/libitcl-O.a: invalid ELF header**

It seems I can't load files with .a extention, but the same is done with previous version of tcl (8.4) and it works fine. I googled a lot, read a lot of documentation, but it doesn't help to go further.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check `readelf -h <libname>` and compare it with your machine's architecture

Comment: I checked as you suggested. I don't see anything strange in it

Comment: Does it match with the elf header of your new(8.5.12) `tclsh`?

Comment: ELF Header's Magic, Class, Data, Version, OS/ABI, ABI version, Machine, Version, Flags, Size of header, Size of section header are matching. There are several unmatched components, but I think they should be library specific.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries come in two general sorts, static libraries and shared libraries. On Linux, static libraries have the extension `.a` by default, and shared libraries have the extension `.so` (plus optionally some numbers to indicate the version). ***Only shared libraries will work with Tcl's `load` command*** and even then they have to be designed to work that way (with an appropriate `Foobar_Init` function, as documented).

When dealing with stub-exporting extensions (fairly rare) or Tcl and Tk themselves, the linking is done in two parts. There's a stub library, normally called `somethingstub.a`, and there's a main shared library. The main shared library contains the implementation of the code; all that is in the stub library is an ABI/API adaptor so that you can avoid binding your code to an explicit version of the implementation library. By building an extension stub-enabled and linking against the stub library, you gain the ability to have your extension loaded into future versions of Tcl/Tk without any recompilation or relinking steps at all. (You also become able to put the extension inside a starkit for deployment, as those use a rather unusual way of managing shared libraries that the stub mechanism conceals from you.)

Comment: Tried with the stub, result is the same                                   `% package require Itcl
couldn't load file "/test_tcl/tcl8.5.12/unix/install/lib/../lib/libitclstub3.4.a": /test_tcl/tcl8.5.12/unix/install/lib/../lib/libitclstub3.4.a: invalid ELF header`    pkgIndex.tcl is folowing `package ifneeded Itcl 3.4 [list load [file join $dir "libitclstub3.4.a"] Itcl]`